# How can I edit a pdf form?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-form

I have a [PDF file with a form](https://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Anaf/Declaratii_R/AplicatiiDec/dclUnica_2020_30012020.pdf). I want to complete the form using python.

I tried to use **pdfrw** or **PyPDF2** to get form fields, but it seems that there are no fields there.

```
import pdfrw

template_pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader(input_pdf_path)
print(template_pdf.Root.AcroForm.Fields)
```

Is there a way to do it with Python?

Comment: That is not an AcroForm form (which is the native PDF form technology) but an XFA form (a meanwhile deprecated alternative form technology). Probably someone knows a python library supporting XFA forms?

Comment: thx @mkl, I will also investigate in this direction

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution? I also need to fill XFA forms using python

Comment: any solution for that?